# Grab set of data from database that matches userid and return it to the view

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to get the row of data that matches the user ID I have. Then I want to return that view to my view to be displayed in my textboxes for editing.

Here's the action that gets called when a get request to sent to the controller:

```
public ActionResult EditUserAccount()
{
            UserAccountViewModel editUserAccountViewModel = new UserAccountViewModel();
            db_user user = new db_user();
            editUserAccountViewModel.UserName = UserSession.GetValue(StateNameEnum.UserName, StateNameEnum.UserName.ToString()) as string;
            var Title = context.db_user.Where(x => x.UserId == editUserAccountViewModel.UserId).Select(x => x.Title).ToString();
            var FirstName = context.db_user.Where(x => x.UserId == editUserAccountViewModel.UserId).Select(x => x.FirstName).ToString();
            var LastName = context.db_user.Where(x => x.UserId == editUserAccountViewModel.UserId).Select(x => x.LastName).ToString();
            var PhoneNumber = context.db_user.Where(x => x.UserId == editUserAccountViewModel.UserId).Select(x => x.PhoneNumber).ToString();
            var AltPhoneNumber = context.db_user.Where(x => x.UserId == editUserAccountViewModel.UserId).Select(x => x.AltPhoneNumber).ToString();
            var EmailAddress = context.db_user.Where(x => x.UserId == editUserAccountViewModel.UserId).Select(x => x.EmailAddress).ToString();

            editUserAccountViewModel.Title = Title;
            editUserAccountViewModel.FirstName = FirstName;
            editUserAccountViewModel.LastName = LastName;
            editUserAccountViewModel.PhoneNumber = PhoneNumber;
            editUserAccountViewModel.AltPhoneNumber = AltPhoneNumber;
            editUserAccountViewModel.EmailAddress = EmailAddress;
            return (PartialView("~/Views/Account/UserAccount.cshtml", editUserAccountViewModel));

}
```

The problem is the repetitious calls to get specific fields from the database so that I can set my viewmodel properties to them. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Use an [anonymous type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) to store a single object retrieved from the database and then populate your view from this temporary (and anonymous) object.

Answering from my mobile, so I apologize if this doesn't compile.

```
public ActionResult EditUserAccount()
{
            UserAccountViewModel editUserAccountViewModel = new UserAccountViewModel();
            db_user user = new db_user();
            editUserAccountViewModel.UserName = UserSession.GetValue(StateNameEnum.UserName, StateNameEnum.UserName.ToString()) as string;

            var user = context.db_user.Where(x => x.UserId == editUserAccountViewModel.UserId)
                .Select(x => new {x.Title, x.FirstName, x.LastName, x.PhoneNumber, x.AltPhoneNumber, x.EmailAddress } );

            editUserAccountViewModel.Title = user.Title;
            editUserAccountViewModel.FirstName = user.FirstName;
            editUserAccountViewModel.LastName = user.LastName;
            editUserAccountViewModel.PhoneNumber = user.PhoneNumber;
            editUserAccountViewModel.AltPhoneNumber = user.AltPhoneNumber;
            editUserAccountViewModel.EmailAddress = user.EmailAddress;
            return (PartialView("~/Views/Account/UserAccount.cshtml", editUserAccountViewModel));

}
```

This lets you hit the database once instead of once per property.

Comment: One question, the x's that appear after x.Title, it says "The name 'x' does not exist in current context".

Comment: I wasn't (still are't) in front of my ide. Try the query syntax from the page I linked to.

Comment: Wait... I was missing a `new { ... }` in there. Try the updated code.

Comment: Okay, thank you!! Just curious why would I need a new {} there?

Comment: @KalaJ because you are creating a **new** amonymous object.

Comment: @RubberDuck, now I am getting this error for user.LastName, user.FirstName, etc... : 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' does not contain a definition for 'LastName' and no extension method 'LastName' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Have you tried the query syntax? Or perhaps you're missing a Using directive?

Answer (score 1):

Only talking about these lines of code

> ```
>       UserAccountViewModel editUserAccountViewModel = new UserAccountViewModel();
>        db_user user = new db_user();
>        editUserAccountViewModel.UserName = UserSession.GetValue(StateNameEnum.UserName, StateNameEnum.UserName.ToString()) as string;
>        var Title = context.db_user.Where(x => x.UserId == editUserAccountViewModel.UserId).Select(x => x.Title).ToString();
> ```

- I don't see the `db_user user` being used anywhere, so you should remove it.
- Class names shouldn't use underscores in their name and also should use `PascalCase` casing based on the [naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx).
  Based on the same guidelines variables should be named using `camelCase` casing.
- you are filling the `UserName` property of the `UserAccountViewModel` by calling `GetValue()` of the `UserSession` and later in the queries you are refering to the `UserId` property which seems isn't filled at all. If this is magically done by the setter of the `UserName` property then I would call this a side effect which shouldn't happen. If this isn't filled by the setter, then I would say that the queries are senseless because the `UserId` property will be set to a default value which won't be found in the database.